# Is it possible to use GraphQL query the mptt tree with single request?

Tags: python, django, recursion, graphql

I can query the `MPTT` whole tree with Django REST using serializer. Now I am upgrading my service to support GraphQL as well. But the only single way I can do with iGraphQL is supply the deep down at most to get the last child node of tree

Here is my DRF and my common technique to query tree
`models.py`

```py
from mptt.models import MPTTModel

class Question(MPTTModel):
   answer = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
   parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

`serializers.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from questions.models import Question


class QuestionTreeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Question
       fields = [
          'id',
          'parent',
          'children',
       ]
    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        fields['children'] = QuestionTreeSerializer(many=True)
        return fields
```

And here is my current GraphQL implementation

```py
from graphene import relay
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from questions.models import Question


class QuestionType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)
        fields = [
            'id',
            'name',
            'children',
            'parent',
        ]


class QuestionConnection(relay.Connection):
    class Meta:
        node = QuestionType


class Query:
    questions = relay.ConnectionField(QuestionConnection)

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_questions(root, info, **kwargs):
        return Question.objects.all()
```

Here is my current query

```
query{
  questions{
    edges{
      node{
        id
        name
        children {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              name
              children {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id
                    children {
                        edges {
                            node {
                                id
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        parent {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Problem:**
It is static query and it does not get all the children in the tree

**Workaround:**
I have to add the nested query to the deepest level in my payload to get all branches. This is not a good practice, but at least it works

**Question:**
Is it possible to use `GraphQL` to query `django-mptt` tree all at once like `DRF`?

Comment: I like your question. :)
Did you try using fragments? I am not sure if a fragment can include itself thus making it recursive.

Comment: @Eraldo No, I did not. I will back to `fragments` and let you know when I have a chance to work on this feature

Comment: @sarit do you get the solution ? i am also looking for same solution as i am working on django mptt using graphene-django.

Comment: @RTan You might need to try `Eraldo` comment. Luckily, my workaround solution is acceptable from business side